# TAB Key does not work in NetBeans 8

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, linux-mint

I'm working with Netbeans 8 on a Linux Mint 13 (Cinnamon). Here the TAB Key does not work. For example if I want to make a Line comment and use the TAB Key to indent a few tabs, then nothing happens. Even manual intendation of code using the TAB Key does not work. The TAB Key of my keyboard is not broken because it works in other programs. It is not a major issue but with time it is getting a little annoying.

NetBeans has GUI problems in Cinnamon in general (I heard it has to do with Cinnamon using muffin instead of mutter) could that be linked?

Comment: This problem occurred for me when I did sout then pressed the tab key, to generate System.out.println("");

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue. Turned out it was caused by setting Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting -> Category: Tabs and Indents -> Number of Spaces per Indent: 0

Setting the number of spaces per indent to a positive value fixed it in my case. Strangely, this value may affect your tabbing even if you aren't replacing tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem on MATE @ Ubuntu + NetBeans 8 beta.

TAB Key not inserting tabs/spaces insted of displaying [TAB] icon in status bar.
Key doesnt work on .java files, but it does on .txt or others format files.

What i did to fix it was deleting ~/.netbeans configuration folder.

Now i lost configuration but TAB is working again.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem, then i try to find out the solution and i just change the version of netbeans 12.6 to 12.0 with the jdk version 8 and it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the shortcut ( command comma - ⌘, ) or you can go into options and select preferences

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJe3X.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsZBj.png)

Comment: It seems the question is related to Linux Mint not Mac OS. Please try to provide more generic platform independent solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I use Mac OS. And I never had a similar problem on another platform.